How to load Pylogit library (without error)
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to use the Pylogit Library. Once I load the library, I'm confronted with the following error message: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\anaconda\anaconda3\Lib\collections_init_.py)".
After going through the source code, it appears that in the file choice_tools.py, the import statement calls for Iterable from the standard collections module whereas it should reference collections.abc. Also, I'm not sure if the owner updates the library anymore. I tried to manually make adjustments to the installed script but I still get the same error. Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem and use the library?

I didn't have a problem with importing the library with python version 3.9, what is your python version, and can you try it on a new virtual environment?
